# Valor dentro de array php

Tags: php, array

Tengo la siguiente estructura php.

```
require_once('api.php');

$data = array(
    'DETALLES' => array(
        array(
            'ITEM' => 'N1',
            'DESCRIPCION' => 'DESCRIPCION',
        )
    ),
);


$api = new api();

$result = $api->envioDatos(
    $data,
    'cer',
    array(
        'guardarPDF' => '../comprobantes/documento-'.$result['num_documento'],
    )
);
```

tengo el problema, que en el array(guardarPDF), solo me guarda el pdf con el nombre 'documento-', no obteniendome el numero del documento que intento obtener y concatenar. este proceso tiene que ser dentro de ese array ya que viene predefinido desde la api.

al hacer el proceso fuera de $result().., obtengo el numero del documento sin problemas con $result['num_documento'].

agradeceria su ayuda estimados.

Dejo la solucion, si a alguien le sucede lo mismo.

```
    require_once('api.php');

    function generarCodigo($longitud) {
    $key = '';
    $pattern = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $max = strlen($pattern)-1;
    for($i=0;$i < $longitud;$i++) $key .= $pattern{mt_rand(0,$max)};
    return $key;
    }

    $data = array(
            'DETALLES' => array(
                array(
                    'ITEM' => 'N1',
                    'DESCRIPCION' => 'DESCRIPCION',
                )
            ),
        );

        $api = new api();
        $codAleatorio= generarCodigo(6);
        $result = $api->envioDatos(
            $data,
            'cer',
            array(
                'guardarPDF' => '../comprobantes/'.$codAleatorio,
            )
        );
    rename("../comprobantes/".$codAleatorio.".pdf", "../comprobantes/guia-".$resultado['folio'].".pdf");
    rename("../comprobantes/".$codAleatorio.".xml", "../comprobantes/guia-".$resultado['folio'].".xml");
```

Comment: La variable `$result` no está definida aún. Lo que estás haciendo es contradictorio, pues le estás preguntando a la API con datos que esperas que te devuelva ésta misma. El número del documento deberías conocerlo previamente y ahí sí concatenarlo.

Comment: Que libreria estas usando para poder asesorarte mejor, epro en resumen es basicamente lo que te han respondido y comentado anteriormente, no puedes acceder a ese indice porque aún no se ha creado. Te voy a poner una respuesta que a lo mejor te funciona como punto de referencia

Comment: solucionado, quizás no de la forma mas bonita, pero funciono. agradecido.

Comment: jajaja OKOK no hay de q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo debes ponerle un nombre que sepas de antemano y luego renombrar el archivo, aclarar que si no funciona el rename debes probar bien la ruta hasta llegar al archivo que salvastes yo solo te propongo la idea no lo he probado porque no tengo tu estructura de directorios ni se si estas en windows o linux. Aqui esta la solución:

```
//Creas un nombre unico
$name = uniqid("documento-");
$result = $api->envioDatos(
    $data,
    'cer',
    array(
        'guardarPDF' => '../comprobantes/'.$name, //Le pones el nombre unico
    )
);
//Luego renombras el archivo con el nombre que realmente debe tener
rename(__DIR__.'../comprobantes/'.$name, 'documento-'.$result['num_documento']);
```

Comment: Hola dariel, gracias !! lo logre solucionar!! curiosamente casi de la misma forma que recomiendas tu. asigne al documento un folio aleatorio, y luego le hice un rename. agradecido por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo muy bien tu problema. No puedes usar `$result['num_documento']` dentro de `$api->envioDatos()` ya que esta función no ha devuelto nada a la variable `$result` aún es unset
¿No puedes obtener el `num_documento` primero y después usarlo para enviarlo a la función `$api->envioDatos`?

Comment: Hola,['num_documento'] se obtiene dentro de $result = $api->envioDatos(), mi problema es que ,necesito obtener el numero de documento para concatenarlo al nombre del pdf, me guarda bien, pero solo me guardar 'documento-.pdf' y quiero se se guarde asi : 'documento-88.pdf'., de todas maneras muchas gracias por comentar.